# Is it possible to order a range of values first and then sort the rest in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to sort by **endSub** column (it can be ascending, but it doesn't matter for this), but I only want to sort the ones that have **idSubscription** equals to 7,6 and 5. The ones that have **idSubscription** equals to 4,3,2 or 1, they don't need to be sorted but they need to come after the ones with **idSubscription** equals to 7,6 and 5 sorted.

I don't know if it sounds confusing.

Example of a result:

```
idSP,      endSub,    idSubscription
XX, 2023-11-13 23:23:23, 5
XX, 2024-11-13 23:23:23, 7
XX, 2024-12-13 23:23:23, 7
XX, 2025-11-13 23:23:23, 6
...
XX, 2026-11-13 23:23:23, 4 <- after all the 7,6,5 sorted
```

I also want to know how do it if I wanted to sort the ones that have **idSubscription** equals to 4,3,2 and 1 but after 7,6 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *case expression* in an order by clause, for example

```
order by case when IdSubscription in (5,6,7) then 0 else 1 end
```

You can add additional criteria to further sort the rows within those two groups.